# How to know which route is being accessed in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, hyperlink, dashboard, breadcrumbs

I'm starting a project php with Laravel framework 5!

I need to make a section in my project laravel for a dashboard to know which page is visited by the user.

Example: **Menu Dashboard** [Home -> Profile -> Settings -> Account ]

And i need know what is visited and show to user: ex: **Dashboard -> Home**

The question is, I use the Blade template of laravel to maker my fixed layout page and use for the other views pages. how to know which view is being accessed to mark in my blade layout?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>DashBoard</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        @section('sidebar')
        <section id="breadcrumb">
          <div class="container">
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
              <li><a href="dashboard.html">Dashboard</a></li>
              <li><a href="profile.html">Profile</a></li>
              <li><a href="settings.html">Settings</a></li>
              <li><a href="account.html">Account</a></li>
            </ol>
          </div>
       </section>
        @show

        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like you are asking how to implement breadcrumbs. I recommend googling laravel breadcrumbs. Here is one of the first results: https://github.com/davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs

Comment: Yes buddy, this is what I need. I used this method of github but is presenting error in the installation of the composer:

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  - don't install illuminate/view v5.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
- Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.4.36, required as 5.4.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.4.36].
 - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36

My Version Laravel Framework 5.4.36, need update for 5.5?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the url/route using the `Request::is()` function, so setting something like:

```
<li class="{{ Request::is("dashboard") ? "active" : "" }}">
  <a href="dashboard.html">Dashboard</a>
</li>
...
```

To set one of your `<li>` items as `active`, which you'd then just style slightly different than non-active ones.

Note that the value passed to `is()` has to match the way you have the route defined in `routes.php`: (Note: Omit leading `/` in `is()`)

```
Route::get("/dashboard", ...);
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim!! I was able to solve the problem.

https://github.com/davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs